# Resources suggestion about linear model

Tags: regression, anova, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, linear-model

I was wondering if you could tell me about some self-learning resources for linear model theories. My professor has been using "A First Course in Linear Model Theory, Ravishanker and Dey. Publisher: CRC." I found this kinda difficult. My major is mathematics. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Reading the whole book on just linear models may be an overkill. This will be especially inefficient if the book is all about "traditional" thinking and does not present a detailed overview of *regularization*. In many situations, regularization allows one to improve estimation methods for linear models, generating techniques like lasso, ridge regression, elastic nets, least angle regression and principal components regression (I will stress: all of those are methods for *linear models*.). I have discovered that all major facts about linear models are covered by

chapter 3 of *Hastie, T., Tibshirani, R., & Friedman, J. H. (2008). The elements of statistical learning: Data mining, inference, and prediction. New York: Springer.*

and

chapters 2-5 of *Greene, W. H. (2012). Econometric Analysis (7th ed). Upper Saddle River, NJ: Prentice Hall.*

Comment: I would say, Hastie, T., Tibshirani is great to present those ideas. I liked their textbooks. I will take PhD qualifying exam on the linear model theory. I am looking for something that covers theoretical details.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you

**Pedhazur, E. J. (1997). Multiple regression in behavioural research Fort Worth. TX: Harcourt Brace College Publishers.**

Of all books on regression that I have had a chance to read, the one by Pedhazur is the easiest to understand. He covers the basics of regression, explaining each concept by using easy to follow examples. Also, he provides a great account of how to test regression assumptions. The bit that I found the most satisfying was a complete step by step example of matrix calculations in parameter estimation. In my humble view, this book is gold for those who want to understand regression deeply